# Terraform with AWS and Jenkins - Environment Vars

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, terraform

Im in the process of setting up a Continuous Integration Server using Jenkins And Terraform (among other things)and AWS. I have a few Environments for my application (Staging, QA, Production) and have about 20 Environment Variables for each.

My question is: Whats the best way of centrally storing the Environment Vars for each Environment, for use by Jenkins / Terraform / any service I end integrating with Jenkins?

Comment: Are you using Terraform to spin up and down build servers from within Jenkins? You may want to use Docker for that instead as it would be more efficient and cheaper.

Comment: @MattSchuchard only to spin up as needed -- which isn't often beyond the initial spin up. Why is it cheaper not to?

Comment: @MattSchuchard just wanted to follow up on your last comment and see what you meant and why.  Thanks!